# Viewport sizing not working in ios

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the `header` in my website set to be `100vh`, this works great everywhere except `ios`. `Ios` blows up the image really  large, and you have to scroll way down to get to the content.

I've tried `height:100%` but that results in no height.

Any suggestions ?

[ivygarrenton.com](http://ivygarrenton.com)

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: Need to provide more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Browser support for vw/vh/vmin/vmax**

IE **9+** Partial support,

Firefox **31+** - Supported

Chrome **31+**,

Safari **7+** - Supported but has repaint issue

IOS Safari **7.1+** - Partial support

Opera - **29+**

to lookup in detail refer [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) link

you can use jquery to set height and width instead of this one. but css is more faster than jquery for rendering UI.

Comment: thank you, the work around at the link seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The "vh" unit is buggy in iOS before version 8. You can use media queries to set the height for iPads and iPhones, like this for a Retina iPad in landscape:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    #header {
        height: 768px;
    }
}
```